# Interpolate irregular x,y points into a rectangular grid with their respective values

Tags: python, grid, interpolation

My Dataset looks like this with around 10000 points. X,Y represent point on coordinate. Z represent the value

```
   x                  y                z
   [ 2.22583283e+00,  7.67818007e+00,  5.756],
   [-2.96918447e+00,  7.74548054e+00,  1.356],
   [ 8.65374299e-02,  8.14656065e+00,  3.678],
   ...,
   [-8.67394831e+01,  2.33729723e+02,  -1.1036],
   [-6.47034331e+01,  2.35621666e+02,  4.4565],
   [-6.35697061e+01,  2.35781284e+02,  -5.6777]
```

I want to interpolate these points into a grids with as less zeros as possible and nearby points remains closeby.

[image: plot of x,y point looks like this]

Comment: This question requires substantial research and is a bad fit for SO.

Comment: Did you even try a first attempt? If yes, plz share.

Comment: Hello, Yes i did. I am using np.histogram2d package but i end up with many zeros in middle. And then i have to smooth it. So i am looking for much efficient way to end up with less zeros in middle